# Check if url is correctly constructed with a language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC4 application that has an extra element in the route/url, it's named language:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "languageDefault",
    url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        language = "en-US",
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Now, every time an action is done I check if the language is set correctly using a custom filterAttribute:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    string cultureName = null;
    var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
    string currentUrl = request.RawUrl;
    string[] splittedStrings = currentUrl.Split('/');

    string currentLanguage  = CultureHelper.CheckCulture();
    var cultureCookie       = request.Cookies["_culture"];
    var possibleCultures    = UnitOfWork.CulturesRepository.GetListOfCultureNames();

    foreach (string culture in possibleCultures)
    {
        if (splittedStrings[1] == culture) cultureName = splittedStrings[1];
    }
    if (cultureCookie != null) cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
    if (currentLanguage != null) cultureName = currentLanguage;

    if (cultureName != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
    else
    {
        cultureName = possibleCultures[0];
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

My problem now is that while I check if there is a language present and if there is not, set one, I don't really do anything if the language provided isn't correct. For example
When a user types:

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/shop
```

He has provided a correct url and thus will see the shop page correctly. However, if he does not provide a language like so:

```
http://www.example.com/shop
```

The check for the language is done, and depending on if this is his first visit or not, his language is set. The problem with this is that **the url doesn't change**.

I'd like the url to be changed so that it shows the language in which the user views the page. In other words when trying to visit

```
http://www.example.com/shop
```

He should be redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/shop
```

And this needs to happen regardless of which page the visitor visits. In other words I probably need to add something in either the global.asax or in the overrided function I provided.
But I don't know what and how.

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a hack, but you could try to redirect to the correct URL if the language is not set...

Comment: And where should I put that redirect then? I need to check it every time a visitor goes to a page on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by changing my OnActionExecuting method:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request         = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string currentUrl   = request.RawUrl;
        var urlHelper       = new UrlHelper(request.RequestContext);

        string baseurl                      = urlHelper.Content("~");
        string currentLanguageFromUrl       = currentUrl.Split('/')[1];
        string currentLanguageFromCulture   = CultureHelper.CheckCulture();
        var currentLanguageFromCookie       = request.Cookies["_culture"];

        var possibleCultures                = UnitOfWork.CulturesRepository.GetListOfCultureNames();

        if (possibleCultures.All(culture => currentLanguageFromUrl != culture))
        {
            string cultureName;
            string newUrl;

            if (currentLanguageFromCookie != null)
            {
                cultureName = currentLanguageFromCookie.Value;
                CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
                newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
                return;
            }

            if (currentLanguageFromCulture != null)
            {
                cultureName = currentLanguageFromCulture;
                CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
                newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
                return;
            }

            cultureName = possibleCultures[0];
            CultureHelper.SetCulture(cultureName);
            newUrl = baseurl + cultureName;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl);
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Now, when you fill in an incorrect language you are redirected to a page with a correct language, if you provide two incorrect parameters you are redirected to a 404 (which is logical).